how to identify ternary operator from java's bytecode
i am working on a java’s bytecode project, and need to identify ternary operator and nested ternary operator.
I got two questions

how to determine an if statement is ternary operator?based on stack
variables?
how to determine an if statement’ s consumed value on stack oprand
is a ternary operator’s result

example:
((a>b ? 0 : 1 ) > (a > c ? 10 : 20) ? 100 : 101
here is a full example of ternary operator chain:
source code:
public void ddddd()
{
    int m,k, n, z;
    Random r = new Random();
    boolean p = (r.nextInt() > 100 || (30 > r.nextInt() ? (r.nextInt() > 4000 ? 1 : 0) : (r.nextInt() > 2000 ? 100 : 20)) <  (r.nextInt() > 1000 ? 0 : 1));
}

structed bytecode:
[
   7          astore] java/util/Random var1(1) = <init>(v0)
 [   9           aload] java/util/Random var1(1) = (stack_var)var1
 [  11   invokevirtual] I v11 = var1.nextInt()
 [  14          bipush] (I)v14 = 100
 if { // block_id: 16 16 => 89  parent_id: 0
    [  16       if_icmpgt] v11 > v14 : goto => 85
    if_false_block { // block_id: 15 19 => 89  parent_id: 16
        [  19          bipush] (I)v19 = 30
        [  21           aload] java/util/Random var1(1) = (stack_var)var1
        [  23   invokevirtual] I v23 = var1.nextInt()
        if { // block_id: 9 26 => 64  parent_id: 15
            [  26       if_icmple] v19 <= v23 : goto => 48
            if_false_block { // block_id: 8 29 => 45  parent_id: 9
                [  29           aload] java/util/Random var1(1) = (stack_var)var1
                [  31   invokevirtual] I v31 = var1.nextInt()
                [  34          sipush] (I)v34 = 4000
                if { // block_id: 6 37 => 45  parent_id: 8
                    [  37       if_icmple] v31 <= v34 : goto => 44
                    if_false_block { // block_id: 5 40 => 41  parent_id: 6
                        [  40        iconst_1] (I)v40 = 1
                        [  41            goto] goto: 66
                    }
                    if_true_block { // block_id: 4 44 => 45  parent_id: 6
                        [  44        iconst_0] (I)v44 = 0
                        [  45            goto] goto: 66
                    }
                }
            }
            if_true_block { // block_id: 7 48 => 64  parent_id: 9
                [  48           aload] java/util/Random var1(1) = (stack_var)var1
                [  50   invokevirtual] I v50 = var1.nextInt()
                [  53          sipush] (I)v53 = 2000
                if { // block_id: 3 56 => 64  parent_id: 7
                    [  56       if_icmple] v50 <= v53 : goto => 64
                    if_false_block { // block_id: 2 59 => 61  parent_id: 3
                        [  59          bipush] (I)v59 = 100
                        [  61            goto] goto: 66
                    }
                    if_true_block { // block_id: 1 64 => 64  parent_id: 3
                        [  64          bipush] (I)v64 = 20
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        [  66           aload] java/util/Random var1(1) = (stack_var)var1
        [  68   invokevirtual] I v68 = var1.nextInt()
        [  71          sipush] (I)v71 = 1000
        if { // block_id: 12 74 => 81  parent_id: 15
            [  74       if_icmple] v68 <= v71 : goto => 81
            if_false_block { // block_id: 11 77 => 78  parent_id: 12
                [  77        iconst_0] (I)v77 = 0
                [  78            goto] goto: 82
            }
            if_true_block { // block_id: 10 81 => 81  parent_id: 12
                [  81        iconst_1] (I)v81 = 1
            }
        }
        if { // block_id: 14 82 => 89  parent_id: 15
            [  82       if_icmpge] v40 >= v77 : goto => 89
            [  85        iconst_1] (I)v85 = 1
            [  86            goto] goto: 90
            if_true_block { // block_id: 13 89 => 89  parent_id: 14
                [  89        iconst_0] (I)v89 = 0
            }
        }
    }
 }
 [  90          istore] I var2(1) = (stack_var)var2
 [  92          return] return


Why do you need to do that? The bytecode doesn't really contain information on how the source code was generated. Also, what exactly generated the "structured bytecode"?

There is no reliable way to do this. Ternary operator is a language feature. The compiler can compile it into any sequence of instructions that behaves correctly, which could be the same as what an if statement would be compiled to. And different compilers may compile it differently too. This seems like an XY Problem at best.

@dan1st, this is a decompiler, the structured bytecode generated base on control flow graph

@Sweeper, in my opinion, every java compiler compile ternary operator as if else statement, ternary operator's if else different from other is operand stack leaves something

Highly relevant: Do Ternary and If/Else compile to the same thing?

@Bohemian i think not relevant, its truely that depent on diffrence implementation, but there is lots of ternary operator not store into local variable, just push a variable into operand stack, and consume by others

So either you’ve answered your own question or you’re wrong.

and don't forget that with newer Java versions we also got switch expressions...

@user85421 you are right, just tested 22 version, it hava same problem in switch expressions, but i think if ternary operator problem sloved, switch's also sloved. by the way, its not XY problem

@user85421 thanks a lot for mention new versions switch expressions problem, save my time!

Taking the question literally, it’s actually very simple. Ternary operators normally have a value on the stack at the last branch merge point whereas if statements have not. The link given by Bohemian actually demonstrates the typical compilation strategy. I don’t know why you say “it’s not relevant” when it is exactly the answer to the question. In fact, I don’t see how your own answer is relevant to the question. There, you discuss whether you can “shrink a nested type of ternary operator into one line” but that was never asked for.

@Holger, I personally feel very ashamed about this question. when I ask this question, i were stucked on a nested ternary wrote by myself. A stack variable is stored on the stack for a long time. It is not at the top of the stack. I stupidly ignored it. its my fault.

@Holger, the ternary is here, boolean dddd = (m = 20) > 100 || (30 > ((r.nextInt() > 100 && r.nextInt() != 1000) ? (100 & r.nextInt()) : 20) ? (Or.a1 = this.b1 = m = k = n = 100 > r.nextInt() ? r.nextInt() : 0) :                     (r.nextInt() > 2000 ? 100 : 20)) < (z = r.nextInt() > 1000 ? 0 : 1); now i can optimize it back to single line. thank you for your attention.

No need to feel ashamed, it’s a valid question and not necessarily an easy one. A lot of commenters dodged it by saying “it’s compiler dependent” which is correct, but still, there are things, typical compilers have in common. I think, the tough challenge is not the expression form of the two alternative values but the compound condition, as compilers typically compile it to an optimized form with no intermediate boolean value on the stack but rather directly jumping to either, the final target or the next conditional. Having assignments in-between is adding fuel to the flames.

@Holger, I changed my answer, this is the method my code uses now

For ternary operator, java compiler generates byte code as if/else blocks, for example:
int a = m > 1 ? 0 : 1

after compiled the class file's bytecode look like the follow one(don't care faked offset)
0. aload_1  // load local variable m
1. ifeq #4
2. iconst_1
3. goto #5
4. iconst_0
5. istore   // store local variable a

the control flow graph
block_0:
    0. aload_1
    1. ifeq #4
block_1:
    2. iconst_1
    3. goto #5
block_3
    4. iconst_0
block_4
    5. istore
    

it clearly shows that

first a block_4 start with store/return, and the operand stack have some value.
if (block_4->prev->prev) == block_0 and block_0 end with if statement.
bingo! from block_0 to block_4 can be a ternary operator.

this is my stupid idea at the beginning, but not real world!
For the following example, the above method does not work
boolean dddd = (m = 20) > 100 || (30 > ((r.nextInt() > 100 && r.nextInt() != 1000) ? (100 & r.nextInt()) : 20) ? (Or.a1 = this.b1 = m = k = n = 100 > r.nextInt() ? r.nextInt() : 0) : (r.nextInt() > 2000 ? 100 : 20)) < (z = r.nextInt() > 1000 ? 0 : 1);

I stucked, this why I asked the question.
After lots of days, I found the solution finally
the control flow graph should be build as following
block_0:
    0. v0 = aload_1
    1. ifeq v0 == 0 goto #4
block_1:
    2. v1 = iconst_1
    3. goto #5
block_3
    4. v2 = iconst_0
block_4
    5. var1 = v3

because of my code will be run each path of cfg,  v3 is easily marks as intersection of v1 and v2, then the cfg should be
block_0:
  0. v0 = aload_1
    1. ifeq v0 == 0 goto #4
block_1:
    2. v1 = iconst_1
       v3 = v1
    3. goto #5
block_3
    4. v2 = iconst_0
       v3 = v2
block_4
    5. var1 = v3

after copy  v3 to block_3 and block_1 and inline stack variable:
block_0:
  0. v0 = aload_1
    1. ifeq v0 == 0 goto #4
block_1:
    2. 
    v3 = iconst_1
    3. goto #5
block_3
    4. 
    v3 = iconst_0
block_4
    5. var1 = v3

ok, the stack variable v3 is ternary.
This is not the full story, after I learned Static Single Assignment Form
if block A (have dominate frontiers && block's stack out's depth > 0)
  for block child in block A's successors
    insert phi node to child head

depend on phi node, it's more eaiser find v3, and no need to loop through each path of control flow graph.
I can't write all here, its too much.
Hope it helps others.
